# Merge Images via Commandline

Tags: image, powershell, merge, png

I'm looking for a way to merge several png images with identical dimensions together into a single file via commandline, like this:

```
file 1: ----------------
        ----------------
        ----------------
file 2: ................
        ................
        ................
result of merging files 1 and 2:
        ----------------
        ----------------
        ----------------
        ................
        ................
        ................
```

I've already done some googling but couldn't find anything useful so far. FYI, I'm trying to achieve this in a Powershell script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear those who voted to close this, from the help center:
"if your question generally covers…
[a specific programming problem]
[a software algorithm]
[software tools commonly used by programmers]
[practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession]
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

My question covers the first and third areas. My question is on-topic.

Reverse your votes, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608487/merge-two-pngs-via-command-line-tool-in-windows

Comment: @DavidBrabant I did read that question before I posted. We're asking different questions.

Comment: @namehere Demanding people reverse downvotes is bad practice on StackOverflow... I'd advise against it.

Comment: @tnw FYI, the demand was against the close vote. Of course, a reversal of the downvote would be happily welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)? The [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) option is likely providing the functionality you are looking for.

If you insist on re-inventing the wheel, use [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) to load and create bitmaps.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't notice ImageMagic had that option. I must've missed it.